# Latin page numbers with XePersian?

Tags: numbering, arabic, xepersian, persian

I've recently been using XePersian to typeset Persian and Arabic poems the traditional way, i.e. in two justified columns. The poetry formatting is done with the bidipoem package, and that's all fine. It looks much better if kashidas are added to even the columns, which, as far as I know, is only possible right now via XePersian.

Anyway, the only thing I can't figure out, despite having combed the XePersian documentation, is how to get Latin (as opposed to the default Persian) page numbers. Any ideas? I know this is a specific and perhaps dumb question, but I can't seem to figure it out. Just for good measure, I'll copy my preamble below.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{bidipoem}
\usepackage[Kashida]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.4]{Scheherazade}
\setlatintextfont{Brill}
\begin{document}
\begin{latin}
Latin Text
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

etc. I included the last line to show that I'm entering the Latin text environment, which does a great job of switching to print everything except page numbers in Latin script.

Thanks!

Comment: A simple solution: `\settextfont[Mapping={}]{fontname}`

Comment: If you only need Kashide from XePersian and nothing else, you can just use `\makeatletter \input{kashida-xepersian.def}\makeatother`. Both `bidipoem` and `kashida-xepersian.def` are  independent of `xepersian`.

Comment: Hazār tashakkor, Vafa! I think loading only the kashida part will be best for me, most of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine the `plain` page style:

```
\makeatletter
\def\ps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\hfil\lr{\arabic{page}}\hfil}%
  \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
```

A less intimidating way is obtained with `fancyhdr`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % must go before bidipoem

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\lr{\arabic{page}}}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}
```

The first line *must* go before loading `bidipoem`, the rest can go anywhere else in the preamble.

Note: the warnings you get with `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\lr{\arabic{page}}}` are due to the fact that `\lr` is not expandable and are *not* innocuous: the bookmarks will be all wrong.

Therefore, as Vafa Khalighi suggests, a definition such as

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\lr{\arabic{page}}}{\arabic{page}}}
```

might be preferred.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\lr{\arabic{page}}}{\arabic{page}}}`

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Thanks for the pointer. Is there a reason why `\lr` is not robust?

Comment: Since `\lr`  uses `\LRE` macro from `bidi` package, the question would be " Is there a reason why `\LRE` is not robust?". Well, I can not think of anyway to do that macro robuts, but if you have a suggestion, then I can apply your suggestion to `bidi` package.

Comment: Also let me say that a lot of macros are not robust in the way you want it. An example is `\textbf` so what hyperref does is `\let\textbf\@firstofone`. Similarly a package like `bidi` and/or `xepersian` can (whenever `hyperref` is loaded) do `\makeatletter
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{
\let\lr\@firstofone
}
‎\makeatother`

Comment: @VafaKhalighi My point has little to do with hyperref; I was thinking to what's written in the `aux` file. Presently, `\lr{1}` becomes `\pLRE{\latinfont 1}` while with `\protected\def\lr#1{...}` only `\lr{1}` would be written.

Comment: No worries. I make that change in the next version.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to redefine `\thepage` to switch to the latin font.  Based on Vafa's comment to egreg's answer, this should be done with:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\texorpdfstring{\lr{\arabic{page}}}{\arabic{page}}}
```

Comment: Which, funnily enough, uses arabic numbers (unless the goal is to use roman numerals) ;-)